# Wait for DOM loading template literals

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, async-await, template-literals

I am working on a project for a SPA using hash and vanilla JS. I am injecting html content with a js file but when I am trying to select elements from the DOM it seems like my function runs before the DOM is fully loaded and returns null.
I have tried:
window.onload,
DOMContentLoaded,
stateChange.

But it only works the way I want to when I do a setTimeOut which seems a little hacky.

Is there another way to have this working? My JS function writing on the DOM is async, I'm not sure how to do the await for it if that's how it is supposed to be fixed

```
    const getRandomDrink = () => {
    let randomDrinkBtn = document.getElementById("random-drink")
    console.log(randomDrinkBtn)
    randomDrinkBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        location.hash = "/random.php"
    })
}
window.onload = getRandomDrink // Does not work
setTimeOut(() => {getRandomDrink()}, 1000) This works
```

This is the JS file, adding elements to the DOM.
I apologize, since I don't know how to replicate the issue with all the different files.

```
const Home = async () => {
    let ingArgument = "list.php?i=list" 
    ingArgument.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
    const content = await getData(ingArgument) // This displays ingredients from the API, not related to the issue I am having
    const view = `
        <section class="Section-main">
            <h1>A New Way Of Making Cocktails</h1>
            <button id="random-drink">
                Get A Recipe Now</button>
        </section>
    `
    return view
}
```

*edit*
I ended up just adding the listener in the same file like suggested by @Taplar below.

```
<button id="random-drink" onclick="location.hash = '/random.php'">
```

Comment: So, bigger question.  Why is this logic trying to bind on the elements here, rather than binding on them in the logic that inserts them into the DOM?

Comment: I was just trying to keep them modular

Comment: You have to have all of your separate JavaScript pages run their code `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* do stuff here */  });`. Of course, you need to scope variables above the EventListener and assign to them within the Listener so that other scripts have access.

Comment: Use ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to avoid the handler assignment and timing altogther.

Comment: There's neither `async`/`await` nor template literal syntax in the code you posted?! I've removed the tags now.

Comment: Please post the HTML that is necessary to reproduce the problem, especially show us how you are loading/embedding that script in the page and where the `#random-drink` element is located.

Comment: What exactly happens when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Bergi I've edited the question, would you like a link to the repo?

Comment: Ah, now it's beginning to make sense. Still, where is `Home()` called, and how does the html string end up in the DOM? The place where you add that should be the one where to call `getRandomDrink()` (as Taplar) said.

Comment: Btw, don't use `<button id="random-drink" onclick="location.hash = '/random.php'">`. Just use a `<a href="#/random.php" id="random-drink">`.